# Math issue in php

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to get percentage of two numbers in my app (laravel based) but i don't get the right numbers.

## Code:

```
$pdts->price = 123.234
$pdts->newprice = 90.500
{{number_format($pdts->newprice / $pdts->price * 100, 0) } }%
```

it returns `-73%`, it should return `-27%`. How do I correct this?

## Update `To those still didn't get it`

Guys I did defined my **goal** / **what i'm looking for** `it should return -27%. How do I correct this?` so I was looking to get `-27%` as the result and thanks to commenters I did find my solution.

*I don't understand all this vote-downs and continued comments*.

Comment: My math says it should return `-73` did you try it on a calculator?

Comment: @Andreas no i didn't so if my method has issue how can i get the correct answer? what should i change?

Comment: I get `-73%` - https://3v4l.org/e8ljS

Comment: You should define the goal. Are you looking for https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_change_and_difference?

Comment: OP I have not downvoted. But I can see why (I think) they have downvoted. The question is only math issue and not something that is related to PHP or any programming language. I believe the question could fit nicely on the Math part of stack exchange. But I also want to say that I do agree with your frustrations about the arguing of how to calculate percentage. You did have a clear mind what value you want, and quite frankly who cares how you get to that number? As long as it's correct. Every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not really a programming question, it's more a math question.

But to get the result you want you need to calculate the difference in percentage.

```
//(123.234-90.500)/123.234*100
- {{number_format(($pdts->price - $pdts->newprice) / $pdts->price * 100, 0) } }%
// -27%
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one,

```
$value = ($pdts->price-$pdts->newprice) / $pdts->price * 100;
$percentage = (int)($value).'%';
```

Here, percentage variable will have your required value.